# Want to learn how to write a gem that integrates with rails, what is the best gem to learn from?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I want to learn how to write a gem that integrates with rails (3) at some level.  I'm learning towards something that hooks into activerecord as I would love to learn that, but not sure how advanced that would be.

This is for learning purposes, so would there be a gem that I could read the source that you would recommend?

Something interesting yet approachable for someone trying to learn.

Answer (score 4):

This guide: [The Basics of Creating Rails Plugins](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/plugins.html) should be a good start for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Rails3, I think the gem '[devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise)' is a good example to learn.

and the basic of creating a gem using bundler, see this post: 
   https://github.com/radar/guides/blob/master/gem-development.md